# Заполнение SQLite из Array, List, xml или .txt

Tags: java, android, sqlite

У меня есть таблица из двух колонок - собственно ID и текст. Строк более 200 и заполнять вручную это не очень удобно. Пытался найти информацию, как это сделать проще - но не могу. Собственно вопрос в том ,как можно при инициализации БД заполнить таблицу из массива, xml или вообще .txt

Comment: из текстового файла либо их xml  - не самый хороший вариант. почему бы не сделать это из sql-скрипта?

Comment: Не знал, что и так можно. Поделитесь скриптом?

Comment: Ещё можно заполнить базу заранее и на устройстве просто скопировать её файл: погуглите "SQLiteAssetHelper". В случае с Room - это уже предусмотрено в самой библиотеке.

Comment: каким скриптом? база данных ваша, откуда я знаю какая она и что туда нужно записать?)) в принципе,я когда-то заполнял таблицу из csv-файла, который лежал в ресурсах. для конкретной задачи было довольно удобно. но там нужно было заполнить только одну таблицу...